# How to Frontend side save and get large json Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of the projects I need to storge large JSON(size approx 20MB) in the frontend side - where I can easily save and get that JSON in jquery.

I have tried below.

1. Local storage.
2. Cookie.

#1. Used Local storage but there is a limitation there only I can store 5MB of data.

#2. I Have tried cookies but that also not worked.

Anyone have tried or anyone has any idea on it please suggest.

Comment: Why do you want to store such a large data file at the front end? I'm pretty sure there are better solutions for your problem.

Comment: Did you look into [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) that is how [devdocs](https://devdocs.io/offline) does it and it seems to work fine. The only limitation seems to be that the browser may decide to "clean up" and delete the data.

Comment: why do you need to store a large file on client side? where is this all data going to be used? how much data is actually going to be used? where/how are you getting this data from?

Comment: What's your use case here? We might give you a better approach on your problem.

Comment: Every 5 seconds I have an ajax call and getting new data from the database. but I have some calculations in frontends side of that records. I do not calculate every record every 5 seconds. I need to calculate only the latest record so, I need to store old calculations on the frontend side.

So, Every time I have not to calculate all records only need to calculate new records.